# Why isn't $\langle x,y,z|xyzx^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}\rangle$ a hyperbolic surface group?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gr.group-theory, presentations-of-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

The group mentioned in the title, $\langle x,y,z|xyzx^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}=1\rangle$, is in between the torus fundamental group $\langle x,y|xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1\rangle$ and the two-holed torus fundamental group $\langle x,y,z,w|xyzx^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}w^{-1}=1\rangle$.

It is not the hexagonal presentation of the torus because the homology is not the same (gluing up a hexagon with that pattern gives you two vertices instead of one, giving you only two loops in the one-skeleton, so this is not the torus group).

Its Cayley graph can be realized as an infinite tiling of hexagons, each of which meet six to a vertex.

Such a tiling can be embedded in the hyperbolic plane, making the Cayley graph quasi-isometric to hyperbolic space, which means that the group is delta hyperbolic with a circle at infinity, **implying that the group is Fuchsian**, by the work of Gabai and others.

So it has a finite index surface subgroup. But this group is a subgroup of the RAAG with defining graph the diamond graph, I.e. $F_2\times F_2$. This can be seen by letting $a,b$ generate the first free group, $c,d$ generate the second subgroup, and letting $x=ab^{-1},y=bc^{-1}$, and $z=cd^{-1}$.

**Edit:**I meant to say that $a,c$ generate the first group and $b,d$ generate the second.\

So this implies that the diamond graph contains a hyperbolic subgroup. But in all the RAAG references, they say that RAAG's contain surface subgroups if they contain 5-cycles. So why does it seem as if a four-cycle (the diamond graph) contains a surface subgroup?

Comment: This group is the free product $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}^2$. You can see that by identifying the two vertices of the hexagon pattern on the torus to a single vertex.

Comment: Also, in the "infinite tiling of hexagons" that you refer to, the link of the vertex is a disjoint union of two circles, rather than a single circle, and so this tiling is not planar.

Comment: Let $a=zx^{-1}$ and $b=y^{-1}z^{-1}$.  Then your relator is $[a,b]=1$.  Since your group is torsion-free (easy because it is a one-relator group), it contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, which cannot happen in hyperbolic groups.


Comment: Brian, your claim that $F_2\times F_2$ contains a surface group is incorrect.  A theorem of Baumslag--Roseblade says every finitely presented subgroup of of $F_2\times F_2$ is of finite index.

Comment: (added to clarify)... in some free-cross-free subgroup. (Of course, the factors may be cyclic or trivial, or the subgroup may be diagonal.)

Comment: I just want to point out that, although the map to $F_2\times F_2$ has been altered, it's still the case that the presentation you give can't embed into $F_2\times F_2$; by the Baumslag--Roseblade theorem, no subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}^2$.  In general, it's a hard problem to compute a presentation for a subgroup from the generators.  See Section 8 of arXiv:1003.5117v2 for a quick summary of what's known. There is an algorithm that works for finitely presentable subgroups of $F_2\times F_2$, as it happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Lee's and Steve's comments pretty much answer this question.  Let me try to summarize, and clear up a couple of misconceptions that seem to be lurking.  For convenience, I'll denote your group by $G$.

**The map $G\to F_2\times F_2$.**

Actually, I don't think the map $G\to F_2\times F_2$ that you describe is an injection.  The images of $x$ and $z$ commute, so the image also satisfies the relation $[x,z]=1$.  Your relator then becomes $[z^{-1}x,y]=1$.  It follows from these two relations that the image is isomorphic to $F_2\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Indeed, the theorem of Baumslag and Roseblade that I alluded to in my comments says more or less (there are some difficulties in getting the statement exactly right) that every fp subgroup of a free-cross-free group is virtually free-cross-free, so we could have guessed it would be of this form.

**The group $G$.**

If you have a presentation in which every generator (or its inverse) appears exactly twice then it is, indeed, natural to guess that it might be a surface group.  And it nearly is.  But there's one more thing you need to check: the link of the 1-vertex of the corresponding presentation complex.

This is called the *Whitehead graph* of the relations.  It's necessarily a union of cycles (in the case when each generator appears exactly twice), but the presentation complex is a surface exactly when the Whitehead graph consists of just one cycle.  Otherwise, the presentation complex is a surface with some points identified, and so the group is a free product of a surface group and a free group.

The Whitehead graph is easy to calculate; in this case, it turns out to consist of two cycles, and so we have two points identified, and $H_1$ tells us that the surface is in fact a torus.

Therefore, $G\cong\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}^2$, as Lee and Steve correctly said.  But I hope the above gives you some idea of how one might calculate this, rather than just pluck it from thin air.

**The Convergence Group Theorem**.

By the way, here's another way to see that something must have been wrong.  It follows from the Convergence Group Theorem of Tukia, Casson--Jungreis and Gabai, which you mention, that any torsion-free group which is virtually a surface group is in fact a surface group.  Therefore, if $G$ really were a subgroup of $F_2\times F_2$ and virtually a surface group, it would have had to have been a surface group.  Of course, there's only one candidate, which can be ruled out by looking at $H_1$.

Comment: Just a trivial addition to the answer: One constructs a presentation complex by attaching cells to a "rose", which is a 1-vertex graph. This is where the vertex identification in the surface is coming from. I think, the confusion in the question stems from the fact that Brian forgot about this part in the construction of the presentation complex. 

Comment: Perhaps you're right, Misha.  But the same considerations apply when you're checking if an arbitrary compact 2-complex is a surface: every edge should be contained in exactly two faces, and every vertex link should be a cycle.

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for the comments from everyone! My embedding of $G$ was a typo, which I've corrected above. It seems like any such group with an odd number of generators in the same pattern will be a surface with a point identified, right? 

Comment: Brian: Odd number of generators is irrelevant; what's relevant is that in a surface equipped with cell-complex structure (with a single 2-cell), you have to identify all vertices to a single point. This gives the presentation complex, see my comment above. 

Comment: Brian - yes, I think that's right.  You should get the orientable surface of the relevant genus, with one point identified.